# Drawing a raffle ticket winner in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
DECLARE @TicketHolder TABLE
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    Tickets DECIMAL(18, 8)
);
```

With some test values:

```
INSERT INTO @TicketHolder ([Name], Tickets)
SELECT 'Bob', 10.37
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lisa', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Robbie', 150.981
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cathy', 97.888531;
```

260.239531 tickets have been bought. Bob owns ~58% of the tickets, Cathy ~38%, and so on:

```
SELECT [Name], Tickets / (SELECT SUM(Tickets) AS WinProb
FROM @TicketHolder) WinProb FROM @TicketHolder
```

Now, I need to choose one and only one random winner (using RAND() is good enough) based on how many tickets each person owns. There can be millions of rows, so looping is out of the question. How can a winner be drawn using T-SQL?

Comment: if you create a temporary table with one row per ticket bought (more rows for Bob etc), you can just pick a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query would find a random number based on the total number of tickets:

```
rand() * (select sum(tickets) from @TicketHolder)
```

You can combine it with a running sum query to find the owner of the block in which the random number was drawn:

```
select  top 1 t1.Name
from    @TicketHolder t1
where   (
        select  sum(Tickets)
        from    @TicketHolder t2
        where   t2.Name <= t1.Name
        ) > rand() * (select sum(tickets) from @TicketHolder)
order by
        t1.Name
```

[Example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107592/)  On SE Data, it always selects the same winner, probably because they seed `rand()` in a fixed way.  If I run it locally, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Amend your table variable to include a RunningCount column:

```
DECLARE @TicketHolder TABLE (     
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),     
    Tickets DECIMAL(18, 8),
    RunningCount decimal(18,8)
);
```

Add ticket data:

```
INSERT INTO @TicketHolder ([Name], Tickets) 
SELECT 'Bob', 10.37 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Lisa', 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Robbie', 150.981 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Cathy', 97.888531;
```

Construct running total of all tickets bought, and update table with counts:

```
declare @RunningCount decimal(18,8) = 0

update @TicketHolder 
set 
    @RunningCount = @RunningCount + Tickets,
    RunningCount = @RunningCount
```

Calculate the winning ticket number

```
declare @WinningCount decimal(18,8) = @RunningCount * rand()
```

Select winner:

```
select top 1
    @WinningCount,
    Name
from
    @TicketHolder
where
    RunningCount <= @WinningCount
order by
    RunningCount desc
```